# Get visitors IP logged

Tags: php, logging, ip

How can I get the Machine IP of visitors of my website logged.

I've used

```
function getIp(){

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($ip){
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
return $ip;
}
```

BUt what I get is my server IP.

Thanks

Comment: I think duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: That post didn't have a conclusive answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIp() {

    if(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') && strcasecmp(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'), 'unknown')) {
        $onlineip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    } elseif(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') && strcasecmp(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'), 'unknown')) {
        $onlineip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    } elseif(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') && strcasecmp(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'), 'unknown')) {
        $onlineip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    } elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] && strcasecmp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'unknown')) {
        $onlineip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $onlineip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $onlineip;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Didnt work.  Can I also get the unique local IP and MAC address?

Comment: Are you browsing your website in localhost (i.e. on your server)?

Comment: Browsing on the server. I get the same IP for the same system on a local network. I intend to get their individual local IP as well.

Comment: Localhost browsing will get 127.0.0.1 or ::1. If your site is public, let other people browse your website in other computer (i.e. not on the same network) and you should get their real IP.

Comment: I'm browsing on the public.

Comment: you are on the same IP as your server is if you have it on your computer. Host it online or let someone else browse it from a different computer